Weird auto-posted comment while using dupe hammer
After using dupe hammer on this post, I noticed a weird auto-generated comment popping up, attributed to me:

This question is similar to: srand() — why call it only once?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. – Lundin
Commented just now

Upon refreshing the page a few seconds later, the comment was gone. This doesn't seem like correct or intentional behavior:
If a comment is posted then the OP will get notified, even if that comment is deleted. So then there will be one confused OP wondering who this guy is who's sending them a comment when no comment can be found. And if they manage to figure it out and reply to me with @user, I would be equally confused when someone starts responding to a comment which I have never written or were aware of getting auto-generated.

It's the default dupe vote comment FWIW but I agree it shouldn't appear for hammer votes.

@snakecharmerb In particular it shouldn't appear and then disappear the second after. What good does that do?

The auto-comment happening for dupe hammers is known behaviour since quite some time.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Yes as noted then: "That's odd. I didn't realize it created a comment that was instantly deleted..."  So maybe 9 years later this could actually get fixed?

Also for the new duplicate comment see this answer. It's been there since 3 months now.

For the sole reason of confusing notifications it woulld be great if the comment wouldn't disappear right after flagging as duplicate. Instead of a comment, it would probably be better if the OP gets a notification similiar to "There are ongoing close-votes for your question xxx, please review the close reason and edit your question accordingly." That wouldn't clutter the comment section and still notify the OP of the close votes on their question.

@Verity There are two correct ways for the site to behave: either no comments at all, or alternatively an auto-generated comment which stays. Also since this was a dupe hammer closure, notifications along the lines of "your post might get closed" are incorrect.

@Lundin Obviously the notification should include the linked duplicate question or else it would be, as you said, quite pointless. It was just an idea though, I agree that the comment should either stay or not be posted at all in the first place.

Can it really be considered [status-bydesign] if it's a cross-site duplicate of a bug that's not considered fixed?

in all likelyhood it likely is by design... even if in poor form and in need of updating one day.

Maybe we need a [status-by-bad-design] if this truly was intentional...

status-by-do-not-care more like. Your earlier comment is actually in reverse. 9 years ago it might have been fixed. Now you should really learn to live with things.
